# Printing Flickr API Response to Console AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, flickr, ngresource

I'm currently trying to make the API call work and want to see if it has managed to return the API data from the external source.

1. How do I print an output to the console from the app.js file, so that in this case I can see whether the API call has been returned?/is there a better way of doing this that I'm missing?
2. Should I be using $http or $resource?

Current code:
js/app.js

```js
var app = angular.module('imageViewer', ['ng', 'ngResource']);

  function AppGallery($scope, $http) {
    $http.jsonp('https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?').success(function (data) {
      $scope.data = data;
      log(data);
    });
  };
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="imageViewer">
<head>
  <title>Photo Viewer</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.12/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.12/angular-resource.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="AppGallery">

  {{data}}

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Should it be `console.log` instead of just `log`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This actually works a bit differently. You will have to define the callback function jsonFlickrFeed. Check the code below.

You will notice two things here:-

- We're requesting the data with parameter ?format=json.  [Check the response here.](https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json)
- You'd notice that the response coming out is looking for a callback function jsonFlickrFeed.  Just define the handler for data into this function and there we go.

```js
  var app = angular.module('imageViewer', ['ng', 'ngResource']);

  app.controller('AppGallery',[ '$scope','$http', function AppGallery($scope, $http) {
    $http.jsonp('https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json').success(function (data) {
      
    });
 
 jsonFlickrFeed = function(data){
 $scope.data = data;
  console.log(data);
 }
  }]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="imageViewer">
<head>
  <title>Photo Viewer</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.12/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.12/angular-resource.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="AppGallery">

  {{data}}

</body>
</html>
```

- Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854250/understanding-cross-domain-xhr-and-xml-data) and for more information.
- If you're using jQuery you can [use jQuery.getJSON instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17430666/how-to-get-jsonp-to-work-with-jquery). [More details](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#example-0) regarding jQuery.getJSON .

Hope this helps! Please mark as answer if it does! Thanks!

Comment: absolutely brilliant answer. Thanks :)

Comment: wow! kind of weird, I have never come across something like this --> good work!

Comment: @amitthk please see question here if you get a chance. any feedback would be really appreciated - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35939620/angular-callback-api-add-error-message-if-fails

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald couldn't reach the link to your question. Lemme know if you're still looking for answer and it's not yet answered. Thanks

Comment: @amitthk it was solved -- see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35951547/angular-callback-api-add-error-message-if-fails

Answer (score 0):

To avoid using jsonp, add the following query parameter:

`&nojsoncallback=1`

See: https://www.flickr.com/services/api/response.json.html